# How to show metabox just in post.php in admin?

Tags: plugin-development, metabox

I want to show my metabox in `post.php?action=edit` not in `post-new.php`. How can I do that?

Comment: How about applying `if ( !empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && "edit" == $_REQUEST['action'] ) { /* proceed */ }` in the function which outputs the metabox content?

Comment: test the `post_status` value which is `auto-draft` when creating a new post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution is to check with the query string from the request:

```
if ( !empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && "edit" == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
  /* proceed */
}
```

But it is also a good practice to use @mmm's suggestion since you are working with meta boxes where you have the `$post` object in use. When composing a new post, there's an automatically created post with a status of `auto-draft`, so let's proceed the meta box coding when the status is something other than `auto-draft`, say `publish` for instance:

```
if ( !empty( ( $status = get_post_status( $post->ID ) ) ) && "auto-draft" !== $status ) {
  /* proceed */
}
```

Glad that helped.